# how can i fix windows c_api error with tensorflow.dll?

Tags: c, windows, api, tensorflow

I tried to compile on windows c program with tenserflow c api and tenserflow.dll from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.12.0.zip founded on https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c.
This example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tensorflow/c/c_api.h>

int main() {
printf("Hello from TensorFlow C library version %s\n", TF_Version());
return 0;
}
```

Compiling is success, but when i have run it, i recieved a mistake that libtenserflow.so not found. Its look like that tensorfow,dll from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/libtensorflow/libtensorflow-cpu-windows-x86_64-1.12.0.zip was builded with some mistakes for windows sistem, becaurse libtensorflow.so is a target for Linux.

Can you explain or fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it looks for tensorflow.so because you were using GCC tools on VS Code's WSL mode (or other IDEs). But in order to load DLL you need to have Visual Studio.

Here's a simple process to run the Tensorflow for C demo:

1. Create a new project in Visual Studio;
2. Configure the project properties(assume the Tensorflow path is C:\tensorflow\; replace it with yours):

C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories, add "C:\tensorflow\include\"
Debugging > Environment, add "PATH=C:\tensorflow\lib\;%PATH%"

Don't forget the "PATH=" before your tensorflow.dll path.

3. Compile and run.

You may also add the Tensorflow path to system environment (replace C:\tensorflow\ with your path):

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\tensorflow\lib\
```

P.S. If you don't like the Visual Studio IDE and prefer to use Tensorflow with command line mode, try [Bazel for Windows](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/windows.html) instead.